# Is Camel Urine Halal or Haram?

Tags: islamic-philosophy

I want to know that camel urine is Halal or haram there are many hadith which claim that Muslim can drink camel urine.

> Sahih Al Bukhari - Volume 7, Book 71, Number 590: Narrated Anas: “The climate of Medina did not suit some people, so the Prophet ordered them to follow his shepherd, i.e. his camels, and drink their milk and urine. So they followed the shepherd that is the camels and drank their milk and urine till their bodies became healthy. Then they killed the shepherd and drove away the camels. When the news reached the Prophet he sent some people in their pursuit. When they were brought, he cut their hands and feet and their eyes were branded with heated pieces of iron.”

Comment: AFAIK any Urine is haram

Comment: Dear Zia, you are almost true, but to the best of my knowledge (as I replied...), there seem that the urine of camel = can be deemed as exception ..., Otherwise, on the whole, urine seems to be haram as you remarked ... / Good luck dear mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                                  بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

In regarding to the urine of camel, based on my research,  I found some related issues and hadiths concerning the mentioned matter. Actually based on them, seemingly, it would be permissible to drink that (as drug (as treatment)).
For instance there is a tradition which has quoted the issue as a prophet hadith that declared:

> إنما استثنوا بول الإبل لما ثبت عندهم أن النبي ص أمر قوما اعتلوا
>   بالمدينة أن يشربوا أبوال الإبل فيجوز الاستشفاء بها.
>
> It say that the apostle of Allah said to some people of Meddina who
>   were ill, to drink that in order to treat … (as a medicine) /
>   بحارالأنوار، ج 59، ص84

**Reference:**

[www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/thread21627.html)

Answer (score -3):

There are Researchs scientifically proven urine  camels even against cancer..but the enemies of Islam uses this against Islam ..so some says this is not true