# What is the solve of controversy on Camel's urine

Tags: contradiction

In a hadith we find that Prophet( pubh) prescribed a tribe to eat Camel's urine by mixing it with its milk. Because they were sick.
My question is that,is that prescription was special for that tribe only??

Or is it also prescription for Muslim Ummah to do so??

If this is for Ummah how I can know in what case this will be accurate prescription??

Then if it is proved that this can be used for the present, then my question how it should be used??

Can anyone drink this urine without mixing it without camel's milk??

You know some are mocking on it.So I want what is the real perception of this issue according to true Islamic interpretation.

Comment: There are different views on the questions you have asked, starting from whether the urine of halal animals is najas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is that,is that prescription was special... is it alsoprescription for Muslim Ummah to do so?

Yes, it was for [specific tribe](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24841/is-camel-urine-halal-or-haram). Scholars believe that some people from the tribe had disease which had no other cure available. So camel urine was prescribed.

> Is this for ummah how can I know this is accurate.......how to use in present.

Well I don't know what you mean by accurate, if you are talking about the accuracy of Hadith then many scholars argue that this is an [abrogated hadith](https://studentsofknowledge.org/permissible-halal-impermissible-haraam/question-276-camels-urine/#:%7E:text=This%20hadith%20was%20abrogated%20by,in%20the%20matter%20of%20filth) . If you are talking about consumption then only a doctor can say which cure is accurate or not and usually in present times no urine is used as cure.

> You know some people are mocking....

Those who mock believe that it is by Hadith that camel urine is a Sunnah which is wrong as any urine is considered impure/Haram, unless it is used as medicine when no other alternative is available.

Comment: As I know prophet & his close companions never did this. But he only prescribed it to a tribe whose few member were sick.

Comment: @ZunaidMahmud I have edited the answer:)

Comment: Please provide evidences supporting your claims and read [answer].

Comment: @Medi1Saif there is no need of evidence as the questioner just had problem in interpreting the Hadith.

Comment: When somebody pretends something without a proof then his claim is not trustworthy.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I just added some evidence.Thanks.

Comment: I actually asked this after seeing a video where so called Islamic treatment is shown & at an episode I have seen him to collect urine that's emrassing to me & he was giving takbir at that time!!!

Answer (score 1):

In a Nutshell: The wording regarding camel urine in some hadith is not the Prophet's words (شرب أبوال الإبل) but the wording of the narrator.
There are authentic ahadith which mention some people got sick and asked the Prophet (saw) for advice. He told them to go and: "فشربتم من ألبانها" drink camel milk.

One of the narrations adds "and their urine". This additional wording is from the narrator and not the wording of the Prophet. The Prophet only advised them to drink camel milk.

Al-Nasai has an entire chapter on this in his Sunan. It was narrated Anas said:

"Some people from Uraynah came to the Messenger of Allah (saw), but the climate of Al-Madinah did not suit them. The Messenger (saw) said to them: 'Why don't you go out to our camels and drink their milk?'" The narrator Qatadah added the wording regarding urine.
Abu Dawud in his Sunnan narrates hadith without this additional wording stating this wording regarding urine was not uttered by the Prophet (saw).

Ibn Hajar and Khatib al-Baghdadi also note all narrations cite the drinking of milk. One cites Abu Qatadah as adding this wording.

Source [Islamiqate](https://www.islamiqate.com)

Answer (score 1):

I think it was only for a special tribe which was found in the Hadith. It is not quoted if it was for the whole Muslims ummah it not.
Reference:Sayyiduna Anas (Allah be pleased with him) narrates that some people came from (the tribe of) ‘Ukl or ‘Urayna and became ill in Madinah. The Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him and grant him peace) commanded them to go to the milk-camels and to drink their urine and milk (for their treatment). (Sahih al-Bukhari, no: 231)